# How can I find out what the value of the capacitor on an Intel Core i5-4690 processor?

Tags: identification, intel

How can I find out what the value of the capacitor shown in the photo is on an Intel Core i5-4690 processor?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an identical CPU with identical capacitor.

Remove the capacitor from a working CPU and measure it.

Then you can put the capacitor back, and buy a new one for the CPU that is without the capacitor.

Please understand that this may not be the best way, but will give you a reasonable guess for the capacitor.

However, you can only measure the parameters of the capacitors your meter can show you, not all.

You can see the physical size, and you can measure capacitance. Good meters show multiple things that might be important in addition to the capacitance, such as ESR and ESL. Or an impedance curve to find out which capacitor will be at least as good as the original.

But there are some parameters that cannot be measured. You can't know if that is a 10V, 16V, 35V, or 50V capacitor.

As you see, the specs of the cap is not known, so even if you replace it with some random capacitor with same capacitance, there is no guarantee any more if the CPU will work as specified.

While I did mention a procedure how to figure out the capacitance, I cannot recommend doing it, as you may end up with two broken CPUs and removing and measuring and re-attaching the capacitor properly requires quite a lot of good equipment and skills.

Answer (score 3):

It will probably at at least appear to function perfectly without the capacitor. Bypass capacitors are not an exact science and having more is like insurance.

If you feel like gambling a bit though, you can find the largest value 6.3V X5R capacitor that will fit that footprint (and is stocked in volume) and plunk it down.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know, and it isn't documented. You would have to have access to intels internal documentation which few have.

Your options are, measure the other capacitors with an LCR meter/smart tweezers and guess that the capacitors have the same value, or measure that capacitor on another unit of the exact same serial number. You would also need to closely match the ESR/ESL of the capacitor.